# Using ArcGIS locators in R to bulk geolocate dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, r, geocoding

I have ArcGIS on my computer, but my laptop is entirely too slow to do even basic ArcGIS functionality.  I need to mass geolocate a dataset, and have access to the .loc locators provided by ArcGIS.  Is there a library in R, or a programmatic method to use the locators for geoprocessing?

Comment: Esri's locators are bound to ArcObjects. You can run a service on a faster machine, but you can't  work aroud local processing on a dirt slow machine.